# Why don’t these mappings to enter Terminal-normal mode work?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, terminal-buffer

I have remapped "enter terminal normal-mode" to `<Esc>` with:
`tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>` and it works.

I also use zsh vi-mode, which requires `<Esc>` to enter normal mode at the prompt.

With `<Esc>` bound to "enter terminal-normal mode" I can’t use this feature of zsh vi-mode anymore.

So I tried to remap Neovim’s "enter terminal-normal mode" to something else, but nothing worked. Here are some examples for `Shift+Escape` and `Ctrl+Escape`:

```
tnoremap <S-Esc> <C-\><C-n>
tnoremap <C-Esc> <C-\><C-n>
```

I tried other random stuff, but I had the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Even with the new [modifyOtherKeys](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31267/10604), I doubt you'll be able to map C-Esc or S-Esc. You'll probably have to pick another key-sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome message! Indeed, I didn't figure out anything else, your link probably explains why. For now I have remaped Esc to jk and it let me use zsh vi mode with Esc (making that possible wasn't the reason I remaped Esc to jk, but it provided a nice workaround for this problem).

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this problem, too.  Using `<leader><ESC>` seems to work, though:

```
tnoremap <leader><Esc> <C-\><c-n>
```

Comment: Not a new answer; just a matter of preference... I chose to use `tnoremap <Esc><Esc> <C-\><c-n>`. vi-mode in the shell still works as expected